# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch Class Based List Views

Tags: django, list, view

I am attempting to set up a website on cookeicutter, I created a new app called "bots" and added a class called Trade and Unit within models. I created two class based views inside of views.py; detail and list view. The trade detail view works fine and directs to the correct trade, but when I attempt to visit the html page that references the trade list view, the page returns the following error.

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'trade-detail' with 
arguments '('1',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) 
tried: []
```

I believe something is wrong with the get_absolute_url, because when i remove it from the model.py the list error above goes away and the page renders, but then the links don't work.

Most of my code is from this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.conf import settings
import uuid


class Unit(models.Model):

    TRADE_UNIT = (
        ('ETH', 'Ethereum'),
        ('BTC', 'Bitcoin'),
        ('LTC', 'Litecoin'),
        ('IOT', 'IOTA'),
        ('OMG', 'OmiseGo'),
        ('BCH', 'BitcoinCash'),

    )

    sell = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TRADE_UNIT, blank=True, default='ETH', help_text='Currency to Sell')
    buy = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TRADE_UNIT, blank=True, default='BTC', help_text='Currency to Buy')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance.
        """
        return reverse('unit-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return '%s, %s' % (self.sell, self.buy)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sell']



class Trade(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular book instance.
        """
        return reverse('trade-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.title



    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bots_trade'
        ordering = ['title']
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Trade, Unit, TradeInstance
import uuid
# Create your views here



class TradeDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Trade

    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

class TradeListView(generic.ListView):

   model = Trade

   redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

class UnitDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Unit

    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

class UnitListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Unit

    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

def index(request):
    """
    View function for home page of site.
    """

    return render(
        request,
        'bots/index.html',
    )
```

bots app: urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
     url(r'^trades/$', views.TradeListView.as_view(), name='trades'),
    url(r'^trade/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.TradeDetailView.as_view(), name='trade-detail'),
    url(r'^units/$', views.UnitListView.as_view(), name='unit'),
    url(r'^unit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.UnitDetailView.as_view(), name='unit-detail'),


]
```

**Tracecback EDIT2**

This is with the Trade model code:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    """
    Returns the url to access a particular book instance.
    """
    return reverse('trade-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

/break

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'trade-detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 136, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 86, in rendered_content
content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 94, in instrumented_test_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 94, in instrumented_test_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
return nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1044, in render
output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 711, in resolve
obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 852, in resolve
value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 915, in _resolve_lookup
current = current()
File "/app/vicki/bots/models.py", line 50, in get_absolute_url
return reverse('trade-detail', args=(self.id,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 392, in _reverse_with_prefix
(lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'trade-detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Are you using namespaced urls?

Answer (score 0):

> Reverse for 'trade-detail' with  arguments '('1',)'

You are passing argument as str not integer. According urls.py of bots you have to pass id in integer not string, So remove `str` from `get_absolute_url` method of **Trade** model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    """
    Returns the url to access a particular book instance.
    """
    return reverse('trade-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

Comment: Hi NeErAj, after editing my code to your comment, I now receive builtins.TypeError
TypeError: _reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Comment: Okay it's added at the bottom

Comment: use comma in tuple args=(self.id,) like after id

Comment: I updated traceback, It now returns the error from before: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'trade-detail' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Thanks @NeErAjKuMaR for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739722/django-urls-exceptions-noreversematch-class-based-list-views#comment80440254_46742179). Helped debug [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52575418/1526703)