# _reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have used Django's `reverse` multiple times in the past but getting this error today which doesn't seem intuitive enough to debug:

```
TypeError: _reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Here's the view where I am using it:

```
from django.urls import reverse

...
...
def show_scores_url(self, obj):
    scores_url = reverse('get_scores', args=(obj.pk))
    return format_html('<a href="' + scores_url + '">Scores</a>')

...
...
```

Comment: This error appeared also when kwargs = {'pk',1} instead kwargs = {'pk':1}

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739722/django-urls-exceptions-noreversematch-class-based-list-views#comment80440254_46742179) comment, putting a comma at the end of the args tuple fixes it.

```
scores_url = reverse('get_scores', args=(obj.pk,))
```

(As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992642/1526703), trailing comma is required for single-item tuples to disambiguate defining a tuple from an expression surrounded by parentheses)

Alternatively, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), using a list would work fine:

```
scores_url = reverse('get_scores', args=[obj.pk])
```

Comment: But, why is this necessary?  (Neither link really explains why.)

Comment: @JasonGabler Good question. It is required for it to qualify as a tuple. I have updated the answer with this bit now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `kwargs={'pk':models_saving_variable.pk}`.

The final code will be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:view_name', kwargs={'pk': saving_variable.pk}))
```